# What is the role of permanent magnets on a Tokamak reactor?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, fusion

Maybe I'm wrong, but to my understand, **electromagnets** can only be made with a conductive coil and a ferromagnetic piece, not permanent magnets.

I first thought that electromagnets where the only source of magnetic field inside the toroidal structure, so I got confused on to why you would need permanent magnets if there isn't any moving part (unlike electric motors).

Comment: You don't need a ferromagnetic piece.

Comment: You don't need a coil or core at all. Flowing current produces a magnetic field all on its own.

Comment: @DKNguyen I see

Comment: if you search through, "tokamak magnet design"  there are no ferromagnets in the magnet designs for tokamaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magnetic field has two sources, one external source created by the coils (mainly toroidal: tangential to the large circle of the torus) and one internal one (mainly poloidal: tangential to the small circle of the torus) generated by the plasma current.